# Why are there thin hairlines (1 pixel?) between ItemsControl items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

When I have background colors on the items in an **ItemsControl**, and set the margins to 0, WPF leaves hairlines between the items as if the ItemsControl wrapper plumbing is taking up a minute amount of space. I checked the visual tree with **Snoop** and all margins are set to 0,0,0,0.

**What are causing these lines and how can I avoid them?**

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<DockPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Yellow" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="DarkGreen">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Margin="10"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace TestItemsControl2938
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
        {
            get
            {
                return _customerList;
            }

            set
            {
                _customerList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CustomerList");
            }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            CustomerList.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Jones" });
            CustomerList.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Adams" });
            CustomerList.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Jake", LastName = "Johnson" });
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }

}
```

## Answer:

Here's the fix, thanks Kent:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Background="#ccc" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be WPF inferring a certain amount of transparency because the items don't fall on exact pixel boundaries. Try playing with the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property on the item containers and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks that was it, I posted the code using SnapsToDevicePixels above.

Comment: Thanks, this can be tricky. Can't count the number of times I've dug into a template looking for hidden margin/padding. It would be good to remember to check this first.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `SnapToDevicePixes` does not always work and moreover, it is not available Under WINRT. For me the best solution is simply to fill the gap between the items by using a margin slightly negative.

```
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="DarkGreen" Margin="0,0,-0.5,-0.5">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```